# Как узнать обработчик?

Tags: jquery, javascript, backbone.js

Я не силен в backbone. Есть уже написанный скрипт, в котором менять нельзя. При нажатии на кнопку backbone выполняет определенные действия. Задача вызвать то же событие при нажатии на кнопку с помощью jQuery или javascript.

Пробовал `$('#foo').trigger('click'); $( "#foo" ).mousedown();`. И аналогичное не работает. Похоже, надо знать, как называется событие. А как его узнать?

**Обновление**

То, что минимизированы еще полбеды. Я не пойму, как до них добраться.

```
define("Transfer/Js/models/n3.js", [], function () {
    return Backbone.Model.extend({
bla bla
        }
    })
});
```

И если писать так http://somesite.ru/Transfer/Js/models/n3.js , пишет, нет страницы такой. Или, может, я не так пишу.

Comment: А исходники можно посмотреть, или они там все скомпилированы в один файл и минимизированы до нечитаемости? Скорее всего, вам нужен View, содержащий искомую кнопку.

Comment: В хроме есть такой плагин
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/visual-event/pbmmieigblcbldgdokdjpioljjninaim

Answer (score 1):

По нажатию ещё может ловиться `mouseup`. Попробуйте.

Backbonejs полагается на jQuery, так что можно забить на чистый JS.

**Обновление**

"Корень" этих модулей, вероятно, где-нибудь в `/js/` или `/assets/js/`. Посмотрите FireBug'ом или другими дев. тулзами в другом браузере, какие файлы загружаются при свежей загрузке страницы (без кэша).

Comment: То, что минимизированы еще полбеды.Я не пойму, как до них добраться.

    define("Transfer/Js/models/n3.js", [], function () {
        return Backbone.Model.extend({
    bla bla
            }
        })
    });

И если писать так http://somesite.ru/Transfer/Js/models/n3.js , пишет, нет страницы такой. Или, может, я не так пишу.

Answer (score 1):

Вам правильно посоветовали - воспользуйтесь Firebug, это отличная штука для решения разработки.

> Пробовал $('#foo').trigger('click'); $( "#foo" ).mousedown();

А чем Вас не устроил

```
$('#foo').click(function(){
bla-bla;
});
```

P.S. в инструментах разработки есть вкладка "Сеть" (Firebug) и Sounces (Chromium/Chrome). Вот там и посмотрите, что откуда у Вас подгрузилось